# How to use the com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport to get an index.html

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client, google-http-client

I don't know how to use this API to get an index.html

Please show me a sample.

This is my complete code, HTTP error 500

```
package com.webrt;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WebRTServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        UrlFetchTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();
        HttpRequestFactory httprequestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT
                .createRequestFactory();
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://www.google.com");
        HttpRequest request = httprequestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
        String index = request.execute().parseAsString();
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find [samples here](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples) and information about the library [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/).  To grab a file using the library, just make a get request for that file.  An `index.html` page is no exception.

Here's a basic sample:

The HTTP Transport you use shouldn't matter in this context. `UrlFetchTransport` is useful for AppEngine apps, but it's just the means of making the HTTP call.  Regardless of which transport you set the constant `HTTP_TRANSPORT` to be (UrlFetch, NetHttp, etc.), the following code should work.

```
HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory();
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://example.iana.org/index.html");
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
String index = request.execute().parseAsString();
```

From here you could save `index` to a file, print it, or whatever you wanted. It will be the full file as the browser would see it.

Comment: @user2354622 You'll have to be more specific. Please update your question to explain exactly what isn't working, what the error message is, what code you wrote that is causing the problem.

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /webrt. Reason: 
    com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport

Comment: UrlFetchTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new UrlFetchTransport();
  HttpRequestFactory httprequestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory();
  GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
  HttpRequest request = httprequestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
  String index = request.execute().parseAsString();
  System.out.println(index);

Comment: Also, please add additional details to your question by clicking "Edit", not in the comments.